# ExtJS dynamically adding tabs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

everyone!

I'm creating an application with ExtJS and I've got a tabpanel defined. I also get a treepanel menu with all items and a class for each of these items. What I'm trying to achieve is when I click a menu item it will automatically add a new tab to the tabpanel, but change the title according to the name of parentNode. However when I click the, for example, home button it adds two new tabs one with correctly configured title, but without any content (http://tinypic.com/r/2whmo2d/5) and another one without any title but content and everything else is configured as in the class definition file (http://tinypic.com/r/105thyb/5). How can I manage to get one tab with title plus the content?

Thanks for any answer.

Menu JSON example:

```
{
    "children": [
    {
        "text": "Home",
        "leaf": true,
        "dbName": "home"
    },
    {
        "text": "Sveatlo",
        "expanded": false,
        "leaf": false,
        "dbName": "sveatlo",
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "Vydané faktúry",
                "leaf": true,
                "dbName": "vydane-faktury"
            },
            {
                "text": "Prijaté faktúry",
                "leaf": true,
                "dbName": "prijate-faktury"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "Hájočka",
        "expanded": false,
        "leaf": false,
        "dbName": "hajocka",
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "Vydané faktúry",
                "leaf": true,
                "dbName": "vydane-faktury"
            },
            {
                "text": "Prijaté faktúry",
                "leaf": true,
                "dbName": "prijate-faktury"
            }
        ]
    }
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

The code adding a new tab (from the Main controller):

```
setMenuItem: function(record){
    var dbName = record.get('dbName');
    var classname;
    if(record.isLeaf()){
        classname = 'Fleximanager.view.pages.' + Ext.String.createVarName(dbName);
    } else {
        classname = 'Fleximanager.view.pages.CorpMain';
    }
    var tabPanel = Ext.getCmp('flexitabs');
    var tabId = dbName + 'tab'
    var tabIndex = tabPanel.items.findIndex('id', tabId)


    if(tabIndex != -1){
        tabPanel.setActiveTab(tabIndex);
    } else {
        if(record.isLeaf() && dbName != 'home'){
            tabPanel.add(Ext.create(classname),{
                title: record.parentNode.get('text') + ' - ' + record.get('text')
            });
        } else {
            tabPanel.add(Ext.create(classname),{
                title: record.get('text')
            });
        }
        tabPanel.setActiveTab(tabId);
    }
}
```

My tabpanel:

```
Ext.define('Fleximanager.view.main.TabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.flexitabs',
    id: 'flexitabs',

    layout: {
        type: 'fit',
    },
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',

    items: [{
        title: 'Start',
        closable: true,
        layout: 'vbox',
        id: 'starttab',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            border: 5,
            html: 'Statistics',
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    element: 'el',
                    fn: function(){
                        Ext.getCmp('statsMenu').expand(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        },{
            xtype: 'panel',
            border: 5,
            html: 'Contacts',
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    element: 'el',
                    fn: function(){
                        Ext.getCmp('contactsMenu').expand(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        },{
            xtype: 'panel',
            border: 5,
            html: 'Calendar',
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    element: 'el',
                    fn: function(){
                        Ext.getCmp('calendarMenu').expand(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

And for example the definition of one of my menu items:

```
Ext.define('Fleximanager.view.pages.home', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'hometab',
    id: 'hometab',

    closable: true,
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: 'HOME TAB'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have something wrong in code which adds tab to panel. Try this:

```
if (record.isLeaf() && dbName != 'home') {
    tabPanel.add(Ext.create(classname, {
        title: record.parentNode.get('text') + ' - ' + record.get('text')
    }));
} else {
    tabPanel.add(Ext.create(classname, {
        title: record.get('text')
    }));
}
```

In your code, you add 2 tabs - one created from classname, and one which have only title. IMO you should apply title to tab created from classname, that is why it should go as second argument for `Ext.create`.

Comment: Thanks, I've noticed it like 5 mins ago, it was a typo :)